# Windows 10 getting stuck on the Welcome screen during logon

Tags: windows, windows-10, login

I have a new computer that I just installed Windows 10 Pro on. (It's still not activated though.) It has all the latest updates.

So once in awhile when I try to log in after the box was locked (WinKey+L sequence), it gets stuck on this screen (just took the picture):

[image]

I saw this happen already twice. The first time it happened, I let it spin like that the whole night. Then in the morning, I tried Ctrl+Alt+Del, or quickly pressing the power button. The message changed to "shutting down" but that was it.

So eventually I had to press and hold the power button for about 5 seconds to kill the power to the box. That rebooted it...

Does anyone know why does it get stuck like this? And if it does it again, is there a way to "un-stuck" it without killing the power?

PS. This is a local desktop. It has a single local Windows account that is an administrator. The Windows account has a password, but is set up for autologon during boot. I installed this Windows 10 literally two weeks ago. So it's almost mint-fresh with the stock setup.

Comment: It could be a myriad of things... Next time it occurs, boot into _Safe Mode_. If it logs in fine, check the graphics driver ver, determine if there's an updated driver & if so, uninstall current driver via Device Manager in Safe Mode.  **Safe Mode without logging in** (not set to auto-login): Click on _Power Icon_ -> hold `SHIFT` down, while selecting  `Restart`, until [blue] Advanced Startup is shown.  Select Troubleshooting > Advanced Options > Startup Settings > 4.  **For auto-logins:** Hard Reset the system twice as soon as BIOS/UEFI hands off to the Windows Bootloder (spinning circle).

Comment: _**Clarification:**_ Interrupting the Windows Bootloader twice in a row, before it's able to load the login screen, will auto launch WinRE and Startup Repair.  Once it finishes, the user will need to select _Advanced Options_ (IIRC), then see previous comment.  [Advanced Startup Options](https://www.lifewire.com/advanced-startup-options-2625805)  &  [Safe Mode access](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-access-advanced-startup-options-in-windows-10-or-8-2626229)

Comment: @JW0914: Thanks for the info. Just from curiosity though. How would a graphics card driver be responsible for a logon screen? And also. If it happens again, is there a way to tell what's holding it up -- maybe something that I should be looking up in the event log?

Comment: Graphics drivers are responsible for creating the drawings that give us a login screen =]  

Specifically to your issue, there is a known issue where this is caused from a graphic's drivers that needs to be updated.  If you can boot into Safe Mode fine, it's likely the graphic's driver that's the cause.  Beyond that however, I have no clue how one would go about troubleshooting.

Comment: @JW0914: Thank you for trying to help, but what you said above makes no sense. In other words why would the graphics driver render that lock screen image in my screenshot just fine but then decided to fail when I clicked the lock screen to log in? Oh, and how about that spinny wheel thing that it was drawing just fine for all that time?

Comment: You'll need to do some research via google to get the technical answers you're looking for _(you'll need to research what occurs on the backend in Windows when it loads the login screen and what occurs on the backend when login is accepted)_.  Again, there is a known bug in Windows that causes what you experienced, so when it occurs again, reboot into Safe Mode and if you can login, it's the graphics driver that is the issue.

Comment: @JW0914: OK. I appreciate it.

Comment: @c0000fd Have you found an answer to this?  My laptop get's stuck on the welcome screen after entering my pin and will sit there and spin for up to 24 hours sometimes but never less than 6-7 hours.  My files/computer is discoverable on my network and I can login via TeamViewer (just to see the welcome screen) so background programs are initiating.